# CSV download not working on live but localhost

Tags: php, apache, drupal, csv

I am facing a problem with the CSV download on live though it's working on localhost.

I have gone through the [File download for csv works in local host but not when live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977022/file-download-for-csv-works-in-local-host-but-not-when-live)

, but that method also didn't worked out for me. I tried with it.

Here is my code, please have a look -

```
    //Final function, called from module file.
function event_signup_download_detail($nid)
{  
    module_load_include('inc', 'signup_event', 'event_signup_view');
    $csv_output = '';
    $csv_output .= "Role,Last name,First Name,Patrol,Position,Home phone,Cell Phone,Email,Payment Date,Unit Join Date,Payment Status\n";           
    $nid = 2001;

    // add the paid users to the csv 
    $csv_output .= getPaidScoutUsers($nid);

    // get unpaid users, add them to the csv
    $csv_output .= getUnpaidUsers($nid);

    header('Content-type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"Registration_information.csv\"');
    echo $csv_output;
    exit; 

}
```

It is simply outputting the result on page. Which I need in CSV file, which is suppose to be downloaded..

As per the comments, I am suppose to change in my .htaccess but the thing is, downloading csv is already working on other pages with same line of code, so it must work here too..

I don't understand, how this print is terminating the download to be started...

Comment: What happens if you reduce the number of spaces between `attachment;` and `filename` in the content disposition header?  There should be one and only one.  What happens if you remove the quotes around the filename?  What browsers have you tested this in?  Also, do note that *some* versions of Excel do not take kindly to getting CSV content when they were expecting an actual XLS file, and may behave oddly if the user opens directly instead of saving the file to disk first.

Comment: I reduced the spaces between them after seeing this in comment of same problem but didn't work..
I checked with quote removed too, same result..
Tested on firefox & chrome..

Comment: I understand the problem with csv with excel but in that case it should ask whether user want to open it or save to disk like setup at my localhost is doing if I click the same link..

Comment: It's done by help of chatroom...

Answer (score 0):

Add this 
header('Content-type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"; charset=utf-8');
Instead of header('Content-type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"');

Answer (score -1):

You need to force the download with your server config. On Apache this can done in your .htaccess file with

```
 AddType application/octet-stream .csv
```

Comment: I opened my .htaccess which stays to my public_html folder at server and added this line. But still it's doing the same.. I just have to add this line at the end or have to care something else ?

Comment: you need to make sure the server is configured to allow htaccess files too

Comment: Is apache need to be restarted or does any other .htaccess also works except the default one which stays in base folder ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart. Also check that your header is set properly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12623101/201623 Check out the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: It doesn't work in that way. I am forwarded to white screen if I use @readfile($csv_output);

Comment: Remove the @. It surpresses errors.. hence the white screen... (you probably have an error in your readfile().

Comment: Tell me one thing - How to check that whether .htaccess file which stays at my root folder is allowed by apache configuration or not ?

Comment: And the thing is csv download is working on other pages of the site with same line of code so but not here...so how can it be the issue of .htaccess ?

Comment: -1, this is not only bad practice, it also doesn't apply in any way whatsoever to the question being asked.

Comment: @RajeevK your question initially said nothing about this working on other pages of site, only that it was "working on localhost but not on the live server". This indicated to me that the issue was with the differences in server configuration and the solution I offered is something that I have seen solve similar problems in the past. Best to get all relevant information in your question to begin with so that early answers don't end up looking irrelevant after later edits as has happened here.